# Convert from ScreenToWorldPoint gives me wrong values

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates

I instantiate through script some `GameObjects` using the below code:

```c#
for (int x = 0; x < data.game.Length; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < data.game[x].LayerList.Length; y++)
    {
        int posX = data.game[x].LayerList[y].PositionOnMapX;
        int posY = data.game[x].LayerList[y].PositionOnMapY; 

        InsertWord(data.game[x].LayerList[y].Word, data.game[x].LayerList[y].Direction, posX, posY, boardHeight);
    }
}
```

and

```c#
private void InsertWord(string word, int direction, int positionX, int positionY, int boardHeight)
{

    int x = positionX;
    int y = boardHeight - positionY;

    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    {
        string letter = word.Substring(i, 1);
        tileText.text = letter;

        Vector2 tempPosition = new Vector2(x, y);

        /// Instantiate Background Tile
        GameObject backgroundTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, tempPosition, Quaternion.identity, this.transform) as GameObject;
        backgroundTile.name = letter + " ( " + x + "," + y + ")";
        allTiles[x, y] = backgroundTile;

        if (direction == 0)
            x += 1;
        else
            y -= 1;
    }
}
```

The objects are instantiated correctly. The problem is that they are instantiated in Screen View coordinates but I need to convert them to World Point because they are off the screen.

I tried to convert `tempPosition` to WorldCoordinates: 
`Vector3 screenVector = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(x,y,10))`

but all of the instantiated `GameObjects` get the same X,Y,Z (2.3 , 5, 0).

[image]

Comment: where do `x` and `y` come from in your method `InsertWord`? It should probably be `positionX` and `positionY` instead?

Comment: Also when using `ScreenToWorldPoint` you pass in pixel coordinates .. by everytime changing that coordinate by `1 pixel` it is a really tiny difference so the reslting position might look the same. if the objects end up on `z=0` your camera seems to be on `z = -10`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add X and Y. I edited my answer.

Comment: @derHugo Added a screenshot also.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are passing world coordinates from here:

`int posX = data.game[x].LayerList[y].PositionOnMapX;`

You should scale the parent GameObject preferably to be in the center of the camera view.

You should do this based on the max tiles in X and max tiles in Y so its centered.

[image]

Like this, you parent object needs to be moved and scaled.

Comment: The posX is just the position I have in the JSON so I know at which position each letter should be placed. Can you explain me how to scale the parent GameObject to be in center of camera view? I already tried  `camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` without success.

Comment: the parent Board GameObject is in the center of Camera View at 0,0

Comment: The problem is that you are spawning them far off the parent gameObject, you need to create adjustement code for this, or easier, just create a grid in place and fill it using your JSON coordinates, the already positioned tiles would be a matrix and the JSON just fill them